# Eclipse + Tomcat: Web app checks for TLD, how to stop?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7

I've got a Maven project the gives me a war file.

If I deploy this was direct to Tomcat7.0.33 it seems to work fine.

If I start tomcat from inside eclipse, then I get errors to do with looking up TLD's

i.e. JSTL tld missing and "http://www.springframework.org/security/tags cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application"

Can anyone give me a clue as to why?

It almost like the property '
< constant name="struts.devMode" value="**false**" />' has been set to true.

Any ideas would be great!

Thanks
Jeff Porter

Edit: The wars were the same. Checked via BeyondCompare. 
If I find a solution, I will post it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you using the same instance of tomcat in both cases (standalone/ eclipse)?
2. Are you sure are you deploying exactly the same jars set in both cases?
   Check in eclipse what is deployment assembly ( Click on Web-Project -> Choose properties for the web project -> click Deployment Assembly ) for your web project, there can you see   what is deployed when using eclipse)?

It is hard to say exactly what is wrong, but if you have the same tomcat instances in both cases should be a problem only in deployed jars (not all is deployed in eclipse, or in wrong version is deployed, or too much is deployed and some jars conflict tomcat jars).

I had similar problem but long time ago. As I remember there was a library version problem. This what I deployed was in conflict with some tomcat jars.